# Scrolling toggle between fixed/static misaligns element in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, scroll, position

Cheers!

I have a `<header>`-Element that I keep `position: fixed;` when the window size is too small to display both an image and the header below. When scrolling past the image, the `header` should be displayed normally below the image, thus setting `position: static`.

Please see this demo:
http://experience.sap.com/designservices/work/see-how-design-services-transformed-shell

[image: intended behavior]

[image: behavior when scrolling too fast: element gets rendered at wrong position]

I'm using a simple jQuery script:

```
function fixedBar() {
    if ( $('#h1').length > 0 ) {
        var offsetTitle = $('#h1').outerHeight();
        var endImage = $('span.featured-img').offset().top + $('span.featured-img').outerHeight();
        if ( $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() < endImage + offsetTitle ) {
                   $('#h1').addClass('sticky-bottom');
        }
        else {
            $('#h1').removeClass('sticky-bottom');
        }
    }
}
$(window).on('scroll resize', fixedBar);
```

With .sticky-bottom

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

This works fine in Chrome, however, in Safari, the `<header>` is rendered at the wrong position when scrolling too fast.

You may have to resize your window (vertically) until you have the `<header>` fixed at the bottom. If you then scroll extremely fast (using your trackpad) and slowly scroll back up, the `<header>` will (occasionally) be rendered on top of the summary text, rather than directly adjacent to the top image.

Any ideas on how to fix this? It is certainly affected by the videos and the carousel, as the problem does not persist without those elements. I have tried to "activate" hardware acceleration using `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` on the `<header>`-Element, but with no success.

Thanks for your help!

Henning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has this exact same problem and was SUPER frustrated by it. I saw somewhere else on StackExchange (sorry can't find URL) the scroll event isn't in sync with the mousewheel.

Try:

```
$window.on('scroll resize mousewheel', fixedBar);
```

That fixed it for me.

Comment: Also, the problem does not persist in Safari 8 (OS X Yosemite).